# VS Code Defaults to msys64 instead of System Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mingw

I've installed mingw along with MSYS2 so I can compile C/C++ code in VS code. That works great. Now I want to run Python code and I've created a new workspace for my python project. The problem I'm having is when I select "Run Python File" from the right side, it defaults to msys64 and this is what is run:

```
PS C:\git\python\calgen> & C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python.exe c:/git/python/calgen/parse-cal.py
```

In settings.json the Default Interpreter Path is set to python. What I would like is to continue to use MSYS2/minGW for C/C++, but use my system install of python for python code. Any idea how to do that?

Another question, how do I edit what is run when the play button is clicked?

I can launch another terminal and run the code manually but would like to know how to change where python is run from the "play" button.

Comment: Have you check the python interpreter? Use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to check it.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT That helped, I can now select the system instance of python. Problem is I can't edit the command, so it fails:

`
& "C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe" c:/git/e1bms/csc_cal/gen_srec.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & "C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe" c:/git/e1bms/csc_cal/gen_srec.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: I need to be able to edit that command for it to work. Essentially I need to remove the "&" infront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @MingJie-MSFT
After creating a workspace and using Ctrl+Shift+P, and selecting "Python: Select Interpreter" I was able to select the system install of python and it worked. You need to make sure you have a workspace created in the folder you are working in otherwise it won't work.